# nvd3 repeating months on x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to create a line chart to display data over the year, and I have made a simple chart using Nvd3, however I am having difficulties displaying the months on the x-axis, I have looked at other posts but for some reason it just display "Jan" 12 times.

here is my code

```
        var chart;
        var data;

        nv.addGraph(function () {
            chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .options({
                    duration: 300,
                    useInteractiveGuideline: true
                });

            // chart sub-models (ie. xAxis, yAxis, etc) when accessed directly, return themselves, not the parent chart, so need to chain separately
            chart.xAxis
                .axisLabel("Month")
                .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b')(new Date(d)); });

            chart.yAxis
                .axisLabel('Tenants')
                .tickFormat(function (d) {
                    if (d == null) {
                        return 'N/A';
                    }
                    return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
                });

            //DATA
            data = getData();

            d3.select('#chart1').append('svg')
                .datum(data)
                .call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });


        //GETTING DATA    
        function getData() {
            var finance = [];

            for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                finance.push({
                    x: i,
                    y: i
                })
            }
            return [
                {
                    values: finance,
                    key: "Finance",
                    color: "#2ca02c"
                }
            ];
        }
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0q10cyte/

//EDIT
repeating months
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your `x` is just a number:

```
finance.push({
    x: i,
    y: i
})
```

A possible solution (out of many) is turning it in an actual date:

```
finance.push({
    x: new Date().setMonth(i),
    y: i
})
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2futpb98/

Comment: Thanks, it does work however there are repeating months, is this a bug?

Comment: I don't see any repeating month.

Comment: I've included a screen shot, seems to show only when the view is big enough

Comment: This is not a repeating month. This is the normal behaviour of the time scale, specifically because you set `d3.time.format('%b')`. That's how a time scale works. You have 16 ticks there, what do you expect the scale to show?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, is there a way it can be done without the months showing twice?

Comment: Yes, there is, but this is a *different* problem. Here at Stack Overflow it's not recomended answering new problems in the comments. So, I suggest that we end this current problem (now you know how to do it) and then you post another question, regarding this new problem.